ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Error on ASP .NET C#
I have a portal with an approval button. When clicked, it opens a pop-up with a different page where the user can approve a request. After approval, the pop-up closes and the source page is redirected using the URL passed from the pop-up.
The approval process is handled in the code-behind, and a JavaScript function is called after approval to close the pop-up and navigate the source page.
C# Code to call the JavaScript:
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "closewindow", "RedirectToCognos('" + redirectUrl + "');", true);

However, on the line of code in the code-behind where the JavaScript function is called, I encounter the error:

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

JavaScript function to refresh source :
 function RedirectToCognos(url) {
            window.opener.location.href = url;
            window.close();
        }

This was working well for years and stopped after recent browser update.
I tried to just close the pop up still the error comes at ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
Error screenshot below:

Please help me in resolving.

So that implies that the url in the startup is just redirecting back to itself.

I tried to comment the redirect, still facing the same issue

Ah, this isn't a MVC application is it? It's webpages - sorry don't have any experience on this - I would update the tags see if you can get someone to help.

Use the private tab of your browser to test please. Redirection responses are usually cached in normal tabs, so you might have fixed the issue already.

I hope you are not testing in production.
